# Which are the advantages of splitting the developer's time between two projects?

Tags: project-management, knowledge-management

I have two projects, with identical priorities and work hours demand, and a single developer. Two possible approaches:

1. Deliver one project first.
2. Split the developer's time and deliver both later.

I can't see any reason why people would choose the second approach. But they do. Can you explain me why?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's unrelated to code

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems to me that this decision often comes down to ***office politics***.  One business group doesn't want to feel any less important than another, especially with identical priorities set at the top.  Regardless as to how many different ways you explain why doing both at the same time is a bad idea, it seems as though the politics get in the way.

To get the best product to the users, you need to prevent developer thrashing.  When the developers are thrashing, the risk of defects and length of delivery times begin to increase exponentially.

Also, if you can put your business hat on, you can try to explain to them that right now, nobody is getting any value from what the completed products will deliver.  It makes more sense for the business to get the best ROI product out the door first to begin recouping the investment ASAP, while the other project will start as soon as the first is finished.

Comment: +1: Management Attention Deficit Disorder.

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes you need to just step away from the code you have been writing for 11 hours in order to stay maximally productive.  After you have been staring at the minutiae of a system you have been implementing for a long time it can become difficult to see the forest for the trees, and that is when you start to make mistakes that are hard to un-make.

I think it is best to have 2-3 current projects; one main one and 1-2 other projects that aren't on such a strict timeline.

Comment: Sometimes I just get stuck, either my own problem or waiting on something from someone else. If I have another project I can at least do more than twiddle my thumbs or read StackOverflow (useful as that is).

Answer (score 5):

If both projects have the same priority for the company, one obvious reason is for project managers to give higher management the illusion that both of the projects are taken care of.

Consider that the two projects could belong to different customers (or be requested by different people from higher management).

No customer wants to be told to wait while a different customer's project is given priority.

"We'll leave the other one for later" is, a lot of times, not an acceptable answer, even though this leads to delays for both projects.

I believe this is related to the notion of "**Perceived Responsiveness**" in a software program. Even if something takes more time to do, it looks faster when it appears to be doing something, instead of idly waiting for some other stuff to complete.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the dependencies involved.  If you have another dependency upon the project that can be fulfilled when the project is not 100% complete, then it may make sense to split the developer's time.  For example, if your task is large, it may make sense to have the primary developer do a design, then move on to a second task while a teammember reviews the design the primary developer came up with.

Furthermore, deserializing developers from a single task can help to alleviate boredom.  Yes, there is potentially significant loss in the context switch, but if it helps keep the dev sharp, it's worth it.

Comment: This is addressing the efficiency aspect - if there's downtime between   the two projects.  Effectiveness is something else

Answer (score 2):

if you go by whats in the great and holy book 'peopleware', **you should keep your programmer on one project at a time.**

the main reason for this is that divided attention will reduce productivity.

unfortunately, because so many operational managements are *good businessman* rather then *good managers*, they may think that multitasking or working on both projects somehow means more things are getting done (which is impossible, a person can only physically exists in one stream of the space-time continuum at one time).

hope that helps :)

- LM

Answer (score 2):

I think the number 1 reason from a management standpoint is for perceived progress.  If you work on more than one project at the same time stakeholders are able to see progress immediately.  If you hold one project off then the stakeholders of that project may not like that nothing is being worked on.

Working on more than 1 project also minimizes risks somewhat.  For example if you work on one project first and that project takes longer than expected you could run into issues with the second project.  Stakeholder also most likely want their project done now.  Holding one off due to another project can make them reconsider going ahead with the project.

Depending on what the projects are you might be able to leverage work done in one for the other.  If they are similar then doing both at the same time could be of benefit.  If you do them in sequence only the subsequent projects can benefit from the previous ones.

Most often projects are not a constant stream of work.  Sometimes developers are busy and sometimes not.  If you only work on 1 project at a time a developer and other team members would likely be doing nothing while the more 'administrative' tasks are taking place.  Managing the time over more than one project allows teams to get more done in a shorter timeframe.

As a developer I prefer working on multiple projects as long as the timelines are reasonable.  As long as I'm not being asked to do both at the same time with no change in the schedule I am fine.  Often if I'm stuck on one project I can work on the other.  It depends on the projects though.

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally prefer the former but management might want to see progress in both projects. You might also recognise inaccurate estimates earlier if you are doing some work on both, enabling you to inform the customer earlier.

So from a development perspective 1 is the best option but from a customer service point of view 2 is probably better.

Answer (score 1):

It's managing your clients expectations; if you can tell both clients you are working on their project but it will take a little longer due to other projects then to say we are putting your project off till we finish this other project the client is going to jump ship and find someone that can start working on their project now.

Answer (score 1):

It's a plaecbo effect - splitting a developer between two projects in the manner you've described gives people/"the business" the impression that work is being completed on both projects (at the same rate/cost/time), whilst in reality it's probably a lot more inefficient, since context switching and other considerations carries a cost (in time and effort).

On one hand, it can get the ball rolling on things like requirement clarifications and similar tasks (so the developer can switch to the alternate project when they are blocked) and it can also lead to early input from other business units/stakeholders etc.

Ultimately though, if you have one resource then you have a natural bottleneck.

The best thing you can do for that lone developer is to intercept people( from distracting that person), and try to carry some of the burdon around requirements, chasing clarifications and handling user feedback etc.

Comment: "intercept people( from distracting that person)" =) good point!

Answer (score 1):

The only time I'd ever purposely pull a developer off their main project is if they would be an asset to the second project, and the second project was stalled for some reason.  If allowing a developer to split a portion of their time could help jump-start a stalled project, I'd do that.  This has happened to me with "expert" developers - the ones who have a lot more experience/specialized skills/etc.

That being said, I would try to keep the developer on two projects for as little time as possible, and bring them back to their "main" project.  I prefer to allow people to focus on one task at a time.  I feel that my job as a manager is to balance and shift people's priorities and focus - and developers should just develop as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

There are three real-life advantages of splitting developers' time between projects that cannot be ignored:

1. Specialisation: doing or consulting on work that requires similar specialised knowledge in both projects.
2. Consistency and knowledge sharing: bringing consistency into the way two separate products are built and work, spreading knowledge accross the company.
3. Better team utilisation: on a rare occasion when one of the projects is temporarily on hold waiting for some further input.

Splitting time between several projects is beneficial when it does not involve a significant change in context.

Having a developer to work single-handedly on multiple software development projects negates the benefit of specialisation (there isn't any in the case), consistency and knowledge sharing.

It leaves just the advantage of time utilisation, however if contexts differ significantly and there is no considerable overlap between projects the overhead of switching will very likely exceed any time saved.

Context switching is a very interesting beast: contrary to its name implying a discreet change the process is always gradual. There are various degrees of having context information in one’s head: 10% context (shallow), 90% (deep). It takes less time to shallow-switch as opposed to fully-switch; however there is a direct correlation between the amount of context loaded (concentration on the task) and output quality.

It’s possible to fill your time entirely working on multiple distinct projects relying on shallow-switching (to reduce the lead time), but the output quality will inevitably suffer. At some point it’s not only “non-functional” aspects of quality (system security, usability, performance) that will degrade, but also functional (system failing to accomplish its job, functional failures).

Answer (score 0):

By splitting the time between two projects, you can reduce the risk of delaying one project because of another.

Let's assume the estimate for both projects is 3 months each. By doing it serially, one after the other, you should be able to deliver the first project after 3 months, the second project 3 months later (i.e. after 6 months). But, as things go in software development, chances are that the first project encounters some problems so it takes 12 months instead. Or, even worse, goes into the "in use, but never quite finished" purgatory. The second project starts late or even *never*!

By splitting resources, you avoid this problem. If everything goes well with the second project, you are able to deliver it after 6 months, no matter how well the first project does.

Comment: If the first project was worth spending a year on, it must be important, or else it would've been culled. And if is important, it is worth getting done even if it takes a year.

Answer (score 0):

The real life situations where working on multiple projects *can* be an advantage is in the case where the spec is unclear (every time) and the customer is often unavailable for clarification. In those cases you can just switch to the other project.
This will cause some task switching and should be avoided in a perfect world, but then again...

This is basically my professional life in a nutshell :-)